# Rename file on FTP push | SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ftp

Below is my code to push a file with SQL to another server.

```
 EXEC [ftpPushRegisteredSSIS] '12345', '54321', 'C:\TCC\Manufacturer Integration\100_110 – DiaryBelle','Daily_Dairybelle.txt', '111.111.111.11', 1, 1
```

---

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FtpPushRegisterSSIS]
    @User VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(50),
    @sourceDir VARCHAR(250),
    @SourceFiles VARCHAR(50),
    @DestinationFTPServer VARCHAR(50),
    @DestinationFTPPath VARCHAR(250),
    @Overwrite BIT,
    @isASCII BIT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @overwriteTF VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @isASCIITF VARCHAR(5)

    SET @overwriteTF = 'true'
    SET @isASCIITF = 'true'

    IF @Overwrite = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @overwriteTF = 'false'
    END

    IF @isASCII = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @isASCIITF = 'false'
    END

--  DECLARE @FtpPackage VARCHAR(150)
--  SET @FtpPackage = 'E:\ftpProcTesting\ftpPush.dtsx'
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @params VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @params =   ' /set \package.variables[ftpUser].Value;"' +           @User + '"'+
                    ' /set \package.variables[ftpServer].Value;"' +         @DestinationFTPServer + '"'+
                    ' /set \package.Variables[sourceDir].Value;"' +         @sourceDir + '"' +
                    ' /set \package.variables[sourceFiles].Value;"' +       @SourceFiles + '"'+
                    ' /set \package.variables[destiPath].Value;"/' +        @DestinationFTPPath + '"' +
                    ' /set \package.variables[ftpPass].Value;"' +           @Password + '"' +
                    ' /set \package.variables[overwrite].Value;"' +         @overwriteTF + '"' +
                    ' /set \package.variables[isASCII].Value;"' +           @isASCIITF + '"'


    -- FOR Filesystem package SET @cmd = 'dtexec /f "'+@FtpPackage+'" /Rep N' --set N to V for verbose logging
    SET @cmd = 'dtexec /sq ' + 'ftpPush' + ' /ser DBNAME '
    SET @cmd = @cmd + @params

    CREATE TABLE #output ([output] VARCHAR(500))
    INSERT INTO #output
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd -- ,NO_OUTPUT

    IF  (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM #output
            WHERE [output] LIKE '%fail%'
            OR [output] LIKE '%error%'
            OR [output] LIKE '%not valid%'
        ) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM #output
        RAISERROR('***|||FTP Operation FAILED|||***',15,1)
    END

    SELECT * FROM #output

END

GO
```

When the file `Dairybelle.txt` get to the server I want it to contain the getDate() in front of the filename.

Something like this: `2012-08-01_Dairybelle.txt`

What changes can me made to my code to do this?

I dont want to change the file name in the current location, I just want to change it when I send it.
So the name will still always be `Dairybelle.txt` on my server but when it gets to them it will have the renamed file.

I know I can write code that will change the file name in place and then after it is send change it back, but I am sure there is an easier way?

Comment: It will be almost impossible to help you without more details of the `ftpPushRegisteredSSIS` procedure, since it's not even clear from what you posted what the parameters are. Can you add the procedure code to the question?

Comment: To do what you want will require modifying the SSIS package triggered by this procedure (which appears to be called `ftpPush`) to specify the filename on the target server. You could either control the renaming within the SSIS package or add an extra SSIS parameter to support renaming the file. Based on the information provided, you can't make the change purely by modifying this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SSIS, it was MUCH easier!

[See the link here!](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/43/posts/10203/ssis-file-operations-copy-file-move-file-rename-file-and-delete-file.aspx)